# Porqué no me aparece workbench en la instalación de mysql?

Tags: mysql-workbench

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno, el problema que tengo es que no me aparece el workbench en la instalación, en la opcion de la instalación le he dado la opción de desarrollador, lo cual en la descripción si me dice que instalará el workbench pero ahora ver lo que se me instalará no aparace, a que se debe esto?

Comment: MySQL Workbench requiere .NET 4.5 o superior y Runtime Visual C++ 2019. Verifica que se estén cumpliendo esas dependencias en el equipo.

Comment: @aeportugal pues si ya lo verifique y si tengo todo los requisitos pero igual no me aparece la opción, no se si se deberá que tambien tengo instalado sql server de microsoft?

Comment: ¿Seguro que el workbench está incluido en la instalación de MySQL?
Creo recordar que siempre lo instalé aparte...

Answer (score 0):

Tu sistema operativo es de 32 bits? Si es asi, workbench no aparecerá en la instalación. Si te fijas en https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/ , las últimas versiones son solo para x64.

Comment: Esto está descontextualizado, tu respuesta puede ser de utilidad, pero incluye una duda dentro de ella ¿Y si el usuario no tiene un sistema operativo de 32 bits?